# How to add id property in FormData object? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data

This is my function for uploading files:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", $scope.files[i]);


$http.post('/api/images/', fd, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
    transformRequest: angular.identity
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

I want to send also id with this file. I think i must add this:

```
fd.append("id", id);
```

But how i can read this on the server side? For example, when i want a name of file i write this

```
app.post('/api/images/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.file.name); 
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
console.log(req.id);
```

I'm using node.js with express.

Comment: What about `req.body.id`? (I think you'd need `app.use(express.bodyParser());` if you already don't) Did you bother `console.log(req)`ing to see if that shows anything to help?

Comment: Thanks, req.body.id work. So simple...